# Using weighted species distribution data to create a scored grid map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, point-in-polygon

I'm currently working on a project within ArcGIS Pro, I have a large dataset (>40000 points) comprising a list of ~120 indicator species as point data that are assigned numerical scores (1-10) based on rarity. I also have a hectad (2km square) map of England. My objective is to calculate the score for each 2km square based on the presence of unique species within each one.

The species list is like so:

```
Spp  Score
__________
Spp1 5
Spp2 4
Spp3 2
Spp4 9
```

And I envisage an output like this:

```
Grid Spp1 Spp2 Spp3 | Grid score
________________________________
1    5    4    2    | 11
2    5         2    | 7
3         4         | 4
4         4         | 4
5              2    | 2
```

What is the most effective way to do this? I would like to avoid having to manually add multiple fields for each of the species if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [summarize within tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/summarize-within.htm) w/ the hectad as the input polygons, species point as the in summary features, and 'Score' as the summary field w/ statistic type of 'sum'

Comment: Thanks, I have used the method above and it works fine for calculating the score. However, to allow for adjustment of species scores moving forwards it is preferable  to create a table containing the species presence/absence within each grid so they can be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Try [tabulate intersection](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/tabulate-intersection.htm)